# Problema para almacenar un TextField de tipo Date

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas noches estimados y estimadas,

Me solicitaron hacer una clase donde guarde los datos de un Jframe, los cuales son (Salario, Fecha de ingreso, bonificación y regimen), el problema que tengo es que no logro almacenar la fecha ingresada en el TextField, después de almacenarla tengo que realizar una operación de los días que hay de la fecha ingresada a la fecha actual del día de hoy.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class EMPLEADO extends VENTANA1 implements PLANILLA{
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  
    private float salario = Integer.parseInt(CAJASALARIO.getText());
    private float bonificacion = Integer.parseInt(CAJABONIFICACION.getText());    
    private Date f_ingreso = f.parse(CAJAFECHAINGRESO.getDate());
    private char regimen;
    int resutaldo;
```

Comment: Primero que nada, te recomiendo poner el error que te da también en tu pregunta.
Puedes ver [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más información

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver cómo has declarado el campo de texto es difícil, pero asumo que se trata de un JFormattedTextField, y si miras la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) no tiene método `getDate()`, lo que si tiene es un método `getValue()` que devuelve un objeto que podrás castear a `Date`:

```
private Date f_ingreso = (Date) CAJAFECHAINGRESO.getValue();
```